# What is the smallest (installed size) ubuntu based distribution?

Tags: system-installation

For ridiculously small hard drives (8GB), what **Ubuntu Based** (although not necessarily official) distribution offers the smallest **installed** size?

Let me clarify:
I still want a certain amount of personal file space, preferably a few gig.
I also don't have a problem with performance, while it is mediocre, a 2.6GHz single-core and 1GB of ram suffice to run ubuntu fine, but i find that it  uses 6-7GB of space. I am aiming for closer to 4GB.

Comment: This *may* be getting close to off-topic, if not already there.

Comment: I don't understand how this is off-topic (or nearing there).

Comment: Per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions), your question can only apply to Ubuntu or an [officially recognized derivative](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/derivatives). We cannot provide you with any help outside of that; if you need to expand your options further and have questions about other distros, you may want to try [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead, where it's more appropriate. But so long as you stay with the official stuff, it's fine here.

Comment: I was looking for anything Ubuntu based, official or otherwise. I understand that it's probably borderline.

Comment: I'm using a fairly default install of Ubuntu 10.10 here (installed a few extras for work), and the sum of everything outside of /home/ is 3.5 GB

Comment: You've accepted an answer, but you still might want to go ask on unix.stackexchange.com so that answers can include all derivatives, not just official ones. (Of course, Bodhi and CrunchBang aren't official, so...)

Comment: You can try this link. I found it very useful-
http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/8-of-the-best-tiny-linux-distros-683552

Comment: Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/336007/ubuntu-on-hp-510-laptop/489512#489512

Comment: Updated link for Derivatives: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives

Answer (score 12, accepted):

8GB is not a small size. You can use Ubuntu with a 8GB hard disk. But If you are still looking for a more lightweight Ubuntu based distro [check this out](http://lightlinux.blogspot.com/2009/02/lightweight-ubuntu-derivatives-for-old.html). I am not sure which ones among them are still active but I suggest those personally.

- **[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)** which runs with LXDE desktop.
- **[Bodhi Linux](http://bodhilinux.com/)** which runs with  Enlightenment window manager.
- **[CrunchBang++](https://crunchbangplusplus.org/)** Ben Young's continuation to Crunchbang Linux. Debian + Openbox
- **[BunsenLabs Linux](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/)** Community continuation to Crunchbang Linux. Debian + Openbox

Comment: this is not the smallest, mini.iso is *always* the way to a smallest install in almost every debian based distro available including ubuntu, debian, and even kalilinux.

Comment: @mchid , yes those are not the smallest ones, but OP asked a whole "distro", not a mini iso based system.

Comment: Xubuntu Core is probably worth a mention, too:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/05/xubuntu-core-new-minimal-iso-download

Comment: CrunchBang [has ended](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=38916). Ben Young has created [CrunchBangPlusPlus](https://crunchbangplusplus.org/) as a continuation. [BunsenLabs Linux](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/) is labeled as a CrunchBang continuation.

Answer (score 19):

Try Ubuntu minimal ISO from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

Choose the packages you want to install and you are done. You can
try using LXDE or Openbox Desktop environment as they are not heavy on resources.

If you want just a simple Web browser and few cloud based services try an OS called xPUD.

[xpud.org](http://www.xpud.org)

Comment: You can also install a minimal command-line only system from the [alternate CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download#alternate), and then customize it from there by installing whatever additional packages you need.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes, the alternate CD actually *is* the mini.iso.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Dejans' answer:

Try one of the many [Lightweight Linux distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution), see list below:
Make sure, that your hardware requirements are met, before deciding on one of the distros. I also suggest you to definitely buy "1GB of RAM" or maybe "2x1GB of RAM" on ebay for a small amount of money, so you can't go wrong with Lightweight Linux and also it is a huge improvement in your work flow!!

- For your current 512MB RAM option, please see: [List of Linux distributions that run from RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM) - which shows you the **required RAM specs**.
- Also **antiX** (see link below) seems to be a good/fair option for old/older computers, to be considered!

[image]

> [Alpine Linux](http://alpinelinux.org/) -
>   A security-oriented, lightweight Linux distribution based on uClibc and BusyBox. Mini download is 66 MB; base system (excluding kernel) is under 5 MB.
>
> ---
>
> [antiX](http://antix.mepis.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) -
>   Lightweight version of its parent distribution MEPIS Linux, based on Debian testing. Core Install: 128 MB, Base approx 300 MB. Package Manager: Synaptic
>
> ---
>
> [BasicLinux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/baslinux/) -
>   A very lightweight distribution capable of running on an Intel 386 and 3 MB of RAM
>
> ---
>
> [Bodhi Linux](http://bodhilinux.com/) -
>   A lightweight and minimalistic distribution, based on Ubuntu 12.04
>
> ---
>
> [CrunchBang Linux](http://crunchbang.org/) -
>   A relatively large (771 MB) Debian based distribution designed primarily for speed and ease of use.
>
> ---
>
> [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) - 
>   Download 50 MB. Additional software available as "DSL Extensions" and using the Debian APT tool, which has to be installed. "Light enough to power a 486DX with 16 MB of RAM"
>
> ---
>
> [Feather Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feather_Linux) - 
>   Lightweight Linux Distribution derived from Knoppix. Now dormant.
>
> ---
>
> [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) - 
>   Lightweight in comparison to Ubuntu, it uses the LXDE desktop.
>
> ---
>
> [Nanolinux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nanolinux/) - 
>   14 MB distribution based on Tiny Core Linux.
>
> ---
>
> [Peppermint Linux OS](http://peppermintos.com/) - 
>   Peppermint Linux OS  based on Lubuntu
>
> ---
>
> [Porteus](http://porteus.org/) - 
>   It weighs in at under 300 MB, making it a lightweight contender, comes with the LXDE and KDE desktops
>
> ---
>
> [Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.com) - 
>   Lightweight relative to most other Linux distributions Download: 133MB. Package Manager: Synaptic (Lucid Puppy Ubuntu Compatible version)
>
> ---
>
> [Semplice Linux](http://semplice-linux.org/) - 
>   lightweight, fast and simple, based on Debian Sid
>
> ---
>
> [SliTaz](http://www.slitaz.org/en/) - 
>   35 MB distribution; Package Manager is Tazpkg with its repository of packages
>
> ---
>
> [Tiny Core Linux](http://tinycorelinux.net/) - 
>   12 MB distribution; Software repository: TCZ packages
>
> ---
>
> [Trisquel Mini](http://trisquel.info/) - 
>   Lightweight version of Trisquel with LXDE

[image]

Comment: this is an ubuntu forum so I feel we should *at least* limit the suggestions to debian based operating systems if anything

Comment: questions and answers for other distributions go here instead: http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

Remove `/usr/share/doc` or something like that. I've never used help files for graphical applications, so I've cleaned about 400MB of disc space. :) (I use Kubuntu 11.04)

Comment: ***Do not*** remove the docs.  They're there for a reason.

Comment: What if you don't want to read them and are just testing something for a VM? Should it present a problem?

Comment: docs can always be installed on a need to read basis and they are always available from apt-get if you need them

Comment: I'd disagree with "Do not" too - it's often inadvisable, and shouldn't be done without a reason, but that's not equivalent to "Do not". If you have a good reason to delete them... delete them.

Answer (score 2):

This one is pretty cool for a small hard drive  http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/

Answer (score 1):

### Updated information April 2018

This updated information is relevant for Bionic Beaver, to be released as 18.04 LTS during this month, April 2018.

With 1 GB RAM it can be a good idea to create a **swap partition with 1280 MB (1.25 GiB)**. That way no swap file will be created automatically, and the following amounts of drive space will be occupied in the root partition.

<sup>With a HDD swapping is OK but slow. With a modern SSD swapping is OK and faster. With a USB pendrive swapping is only for very special cases, because it will wear the memory cells and can damage the drive.</sup>

#### Installed systems in 8 GB

- **Lubuntu** occupies **2.8** GiB in the root partition.
- **Xubuntu** occupies **3.6** GiB in the root partition.

Both of these systems will run well in a drive with 8 GB size.

#### Persistent live systems in 4 GB

Standard Ubuntu and all Ubuntu community flavours will run well in a persistent live drive with 4 GB size, but in a computer with only 1 GB RAM you need a flavour with a light desktop environment, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, Xubuntu.

### Links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_size](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_size)

[Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu official distros, [ubuntu server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/) installs at around 1.2G (for Trusty) and can be a good match if you don't need desktop packages.