# Ubuntu on HP 510 Laptop

Tags: hardware, hp

I just came across this old laptop and I wanted to try something new, so I decided to install Ubuntu 12.04 on it. I am a rookie at Ubuntu. So I noticed that the OS ain't that great in terms of smoothness, since it's laggy. Don't think that the OS is the problem, just the laptops hardware.

- 1.4 GHz Intel processor
- 512 MB of RAM
- 128 MB video card.

I was hoping that someone could tell me if my laptop is fit to use 12.04 or is it to old? Maybe I have to install some drivers or whatnot. I want to use this laptop for college. No need for gaming. Just for projects, maybe watch a movie or a YouTube video, which by the way lags like hell when in full screen (unwatchable).

I was thinking of updating my RAM to 1 GB, hope that will help Ubuntu run more smoother. What do you thing? Thanks in advance!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

that laptop is really old and Ubuntu 12.04 is OS from 2012. So you can't expect it to work fluently. That version of Ubuntu need at lest 1GB of RAM. Try lightweight linux distribution like Lubuntu, Linux Lite or Pepermint.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dejans' answer:

Try one of the many [Lightweight Linux distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution), see list below:
Make sure, that your hardware requirements are met, before deciding on one of the distros. I also suggest you to definitely buy "1GB of RAM" or maybe "2x1GB of RAM" on ebay for a small amount of money, so you can't go wrong with Lightweight Linux and also it is a huge improvement in your work flow!!

- For your current 512MB RAM option, please see: [List of Linux distributions that run from RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM) - which shows you the **required RAM specs**.
- Also **antiX** (see link below) seems to be a good/fair option for old/older computers, to be considered!

[image]

> [Alpine Linux](http://alpinelinux.org/) -
>   A security-oriented, lightweight Linux distribution based on uClibc and BusyBox. Mini download is 66 MB; base system (excluding kernel) is under 5 MB.
>
> ---
>
> [antiX](http://antix.mepis.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) -
>   Lightweight version of its parent distribution MEPIS Linux, based on Debian testing. Core Install: 128 MB, Base approx 300 MB. Package Manager: Synaptic
>
> ---
>
> [BasicLinux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/baslinux/) -
>   A very lightweight distribution capable of running on an Intel 386 and 3 MB of RAM
>
> ---
>
> [Bodhi Linux](http://bodhilinux.com/) -
>   A lightweight and minimalistic distribution, based on Ubuntu 12.04
>
> ---
>
> [CrunchBang Linux](http://crunchbang.org/) -
>   A relatively large (771 MB) Debian based distribution designed primarily for speed and ease of use.
>
> ---
>
> [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) - 
>   Download 50 MB. Additional software available as "DSL Extensions" and using the Debian APT tool, which has to be installed. "Light enough to power a 486DX with 16 MB of RAM"
>
> ---
>
> [Feather Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feather_Linux) - 
>   Lightweight Linux Distribution derived from Knoppix. Now dormant.
>
> ---
>
> [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) - 
>   Lightweight in comparison to Ubuntu, it uses the LXDE desktop.
>
> ---
>
> [Nanolinux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nanolinux/) - 
>   14 MB distribution based on Tiny Core Linux.
>
> ---
>
> [Peppermint Linux OS](http://peppermintos.com/) - 
>   Peppermint Linux OS  based on Lubuntu
>
> ---
>
> [Porteus](http://porteus.org/) - 
>   It weighs in at under 300 MB, making it a lightweight contender, comes with the LXDE and KDE desktops
>
> ---
>
> [Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.com) - 
>   Lightweight relative to most other Linux distributions Download: 133MB. Package Manager: Synaptic (Lucid Puppy Ubuntu Compatible version)
>
> ---
>
> [Semplice Linux](http://semplice-linux.org/) - 
>   lightweight, fast and simple, based on Debian Sid
>
> ---
>
> [SliTaz](http://www.slitaz.org/en/) - 
>   35 MB distribution; Package Manager is Tazpkg with its repository of packages
>
> ---
>
> [Tiny Core Linux](http://tinycorelinux.net/) - 
>   12 MB distribution; Software repository: TCZ packages
>
> ---
>
> [Trisquel Mini](http://trisquel.info/) - 
>   Lightweight version of Trisquel with LXDE

[image]