# Live Ubuntu for old Desktop PC

Tags: live-usb

I have an old desktop PC with following configuration...

AMD Athelon 1.4 GHz
256 MB RAM
40 GB IDE HDD
8-MB shared VRAM
USB 1.0
External Sony CD/DVD RW connecting through USB

Which is the best version of Ubuntu live OS that can be used for this PC. The PC currently has a bit unstable version of Windows XP. And I have a Lenovo A10 Ideapad with Android 4.2 Jellybean which does not connect to the USB DVD writer.

Comment: Close enough: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79555/what-is-the-smallest-installed-size-ubuntu-based-distribution

Answer (score 1):

As Ubuntu usually requires at least 2GB of RAM, you may have a better chance with a fork that runs using low resources, like Xubuntu (http://xubuntu.org) or Lubuntu (http://lubuntu.net).