# Is there an Ubuntu version that would fit on a 1GB USB stick?

Tags: usb, live-usb, custom-distributions

I have a 1 GB USB stick I'd like to use to run Ubuntu with...
The total space is 961 MB - and all releases of Ubuntu/Kubuntu 15.10 and lower are 1.1 GB to 1.2 GB.

Any ideas how can I fit a release onto the USB?

Comment: Do you need a GUI?

Comment: I don't know, but what size is Lubuntu as that is very light-weight?

Comment: @kos wont fit even without a desktop ;) No, what you want is Damn Small Linux (not Ubuntu) http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/ Even fits on a business card. 50Mb footprint, you then add the ubuntu repos and add whatever you can to fit on the 1Gb (minus a bit of private space)

Comment: and http://askubuntu.com/questions/79555/what-is-the-smallest-installed-size-ubuntu-based-distribution ;-)

Comment: xUbuntu Core has a 960Mb ISO but it is unofficial.

Comment: Unity would be soo good though :'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose Lubuntu or Xubuntu. But I am not sure if the final install will fit in 1 GB, so you could use Lubuntu minimal install OR xubuntu-core (I personally prefer xubuntu-core). To do this you have to download the mini.iso available in the Ubuntu website, here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

The mini.iso is a live system for text-based Ubuntu installation. It is around 40 MBs. You can burn it to a CD or USB and boot from it. Follow the instructions in the above link, choose your USB stick to be used as the root filesystem and a base for Ubuntu will be installed on it. Do not install any extra packages in the end of the minimal install.

Now you have a headless (no graphical environment) Ubuntu system inside your USB stick. Boot from it and you will be dropped in a command line. From there you can run 'sudo apt-get install lubuntu-core' for a minimal version of Lubuntu or 'sudo apt-get install xubuntu-core^' (do not forget the ^) for a minimal version of Xubuntu. Lubuntu will leave you with more space for additional programs; in the other hand, Xubuntu has more features and customization, but you will be left with only a few MBs to use. The decision is yours.

Remember: the "core" versions of Lubuntu/Xubuntu do not have any programs beyond the Desktop Environment, a File Manager, a Terminal and some configurations. You will have to install other programs (like web browsers, software centers and media players) from the command line.

EDIT: seems like you would like to have Unity. You could try 'sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop' on the command line to get only the Unity desktop environment, but I am not sure if it will fit in 1 GB. You could give it a try, and if there's no enough space, just format your USB stick and start again, using xubuntu-core or lubuntu-core. Please tell us your experience.

Answer (score 3):

Since the accepted answer by @Eduardo Cola was written, the engine under the hood as well as some of the application programs have grown.

- *When this is written (2017-09-25) all current **Lubuntu** versions fit within 1 GB, when cloned from the iso file to a USB stick or memory card.*
- There is no currently supported version of Xubuntu still within 1 GB. Xubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, was supported for 3 years with end of life April 2017 and the current versions are too big.
- It is **not** possible to create a **useful installed** Ubuntu based mini system within 1 GB. You can make a very bare-bone system from the Ubuntu `mini.iso`, but there will not be enough space for application programs. An installed Lubuntu system can be squeezed into 4 GB.
- This link specifies the size needed for different cases,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_size](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_size)

  > 2 GB is enough for 'CD size' iso files as well as many but not all
  >   'DVD size' iso files.
  >
  > If you want a persistent live system with a decent size casper-rw
  >   storage, you need at least 4 GB (2 GB is possible, but might soon run
  >   out of space).
  >
  > If you want an installed system you need at least 8 GB (4 GB is
  >   possible with Lubuntu, but might soon run out of space). In the
  >   beginning of 2017, it seems that there are no really fast pendrives
  >   below 16 GB. If you want a fast system, install it into a pendrive
  >   that performs well in a test, even if it is 'bigger than necessary'.
- The reason why live Lubuntu is within 1 GB is that most of it is compressed, and expanded to RAM, when running a live session. This is not the case when installed, and more space is used. Last but not least, you need some drive space to store your own files.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must use Ubuntu, you can use an older version of it which is less than 1GB.

http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.5/